# SSRS Report Not Displaying in IE

Tags: sql-server-2008, internet-explorer, reporting-services

I'm at wits end trying to find a solution for my issues with Internet Explorer and SSRS. I have created an C# Windows Forms program that uses the `WebBrowser` element to display SSRS reports to the end user.

Currently there are two report options for them to choose from. One report opens and displays fine. The data set for this report takes about 2-3 seconds to retrieve. The second report is either timing out or not rendering as I get a blank screen.

I think it is timing out as opposed to not rendering because I can't even choose the export to file option. The data set for the second report only takes about 15 seconds to retrieve. I have tried altering timeouts on `web.config` and `rsreportserver.config` on the SQL Server and I have tried putting a `<system.web>` section into the `app.config` file of the ASP project, but none of that seems to have fixed the issue.

I also tried changing the `sessionState` value in the `web.config` but that doesn't seem to have done anything either. Has anyone encountered this error that can tell me what steps to take to fix the problem? My local machine is using IE9 and the server is running SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Why aren't you using WinForm SSRS ReportViewer control? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337089(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I didn't know that control existed. I was using the WebBrowser control because that is what the person before me had done so I assumed it was correct. When I switched to using the ReportViewer control it works right on the first try. This is just one more reason for me to hate IE though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is above in the comments to my question. Don't use the `WebBrowser` control as it is prone to the failure of IE. I placed the `ReportViewer` control on there and it works correctly. Check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337089(v=sql.100).aspx for usage of this control.